# How can I use grep and awk commands on a text file while maintaining line order?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
domain name pointer www.google.com
domain name pointer www.gmail.com
NA
domain name pointer www.facebook.com
NA
NA
NA
domain name pointer www.starbucks.com
```

IF I use these commands:

```
grep "pointer" inputfile.txt | awk '{print $4}'

grep "NA" inputfile.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

I am able to get:

```
www.google.com
www.gmail.com
www.facebook.com
www.starbucks.com
NA
NA
NA
NA
```

However I would like the 'NA' and URLS to stay in the same order as the original text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `grep`, since `awk` can do pattern matching all by itself. Then you don't need to use multiple passes over the file:

```
awk '/pointer/ {print $4} 
     /NA/ {print $1}' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: I dont think she actually needs to do any comparison but if she does then `awk '/pointer|NA/ {print $NF}' inputfile.txt` would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If one of these isn't all you need:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file
www.google.com
www.gmail.com
NA
www.facebook.com
NA
NA
NA
www.starbucks.com

$ sed 's/.* //' file
www.google.com
www.gmail.com
NA
www.facebook.com
NA
NA
NA
www.starbucks.com
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.